# rounded corner videoview in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video, android-videoview

in my application, I want to display videoview as a rounded corners. I have tried placing videoview/surfaceview inside linearlayout with rounded corner set to linearlayout. but it does not work perfectly. I can not set rounded corner to videoview/surfaceview.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It'd be helpful if you could reproduce your code and put it in your question so people would have a better understanding of your problem/question.

Comment: no i dont how to curve or rounded the VideoView and i did not start anything

Comment: In that case, people won't be able to help much. I suggest to look for standard video app code example, then work on them sometime, try to understand the structure and implement your solution even if your solution/code doesn't work or do what you want to achieve. Only then come here and add your code here for us to see, then maybe someone would be able to give you some idea.

Comment: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues/559#issuecomment-716289121 This snippet would help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is XML code of ***rounded VideoView***.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/videoCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/relativeVideo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="225dp"
                android:paddingTop="-10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="-10dp" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Negative padding** is important otherwise height of VideoView is smaller than cardview by half of cornerRadius in both top and bottom side. You can set height whatever you want but negative padding should be half of **cardCornerRadius** all the time.

Have a nice day!

[image]